# ASP.NET MVC 3 routing in /Admin area with name instead of id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

This one has been throwing me so I figured I'd ask for some help. I've got this to work with my "Categories" routes, but for some reason when I'm trying to do the same thing with "Consumers" it's not working at all. Here is the necessary background info:

Routing (AdminAreaRegistration.cs):

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        //matches /Admin/BusinessCategories/MyCategory/children
        context.MapRoute(
            "ChildCategories",
            "Admin/BusinessCategories/{category}/children",
            new { controller = "BusinessCategories", action = "ViewChildren" }
        );

        //matches /Admin/BusinessCategories/MyCategory/edit
        context.MapRoute(
            "EditCategory",
            "Admin/BusinessCategories/{category}/edit",
            new { controller = "BusinessCategories", action = "Edit" }
        );

        // want this to match /Admin/Consumers/JoeBob/details
        context.MapRoute(
            "ConsumerDetails",
            "Admin/Consumers/{alias}/details",
            new { controller = "Consumers", action = "Details" }
        );

        //matches /Admin
        //matches /Admin/BusinessCategories
        //matches /Admin/BusinessCategories/New

        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "AdminHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { id = @"\d+" }
        );
    }
```

Then in my Consumers controller (ConsumersController.cs):

```
public class ConsumersController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ...code...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(string alias)
    {
        return View(alias);
    }
}
```

Then I am generating my link like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink(c.Alias, "Details", "Consumers", new { alias = c.Alias }, null)
```

The problem is that my call to @Html.ActionLink is generating a link like:

`/Admin/Consumers/details?alias=JoeBob` (which results in a 404, if clicked on)
rather than what I want, which is:

```
/Admin/Consumers/JoeBob/details
```

One thing I've noticed is if I change `alias = c.Alias` to `id = c.Alias`, it produces a URL like:
`/Admin/Consumers/details/JoeBob` (so it removes the alias part from the query string, but still puts 'details' before the alias.)

Any ideas?

**Edit**: Rebooting IIS solved the issue for me. Not sure why, but it did.

Comment: I don't know what is specifically causing this issue, but I would strongly recommend taking a look at the routedebugger to see if it offers up any hints http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: Yeah I know about that util - and the link, actually, should be to the v2 - http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are configured properly (I tested them).  I suspect that you're getting this misbehavior because the view that contains your @Html.ActionLink() mark-up is outside of your Admin Area.  If it is inside your Admin Area, you should be seeing the proper link generated.  However, outside of your Admin Area, you need to declare which area you're targeting like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(c.Alias, "Details", "Consumers", new { alias = c.Alias, area = "Admin" }, null)
```

Comment: Actually, the @Html.ActionLink call **is** inside my Admin area. Strangely enough, I got on to the server and rebooted IIS, and now the proper URL structure is being generated, but now MVC is attempting to look for a View with the name of the Consumer, rather than the "details" view - even though I've specified both the Controller and Action names in my route. :-\

Comment: Nevermind - figured that part out. I was passing the alias to the View function (had left some test code in) so it was like return View(alias). I removed the "alias" part so it was just return View() and all is well.

Comment: That is very strange. I tested your code in a brand new MVC3 project and it works for me, so I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.  Good luck in solving this.

Comment: Yeah I'm not exactly sure what the issue was, nor why it was "solved" by restarting IIS on the server, but that seemed to do the trick.